# How to align two divs in different components?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have two components as follows:

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    return (
        <div>
            I am Div 1
        </div>
        <Child Component />
    )
}
```

ChildComponent has another div:

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    return (
        <div>
            I am Div 2
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to align Div 1 and Div 2 horizontally. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Wrap them both in an outer div. Use css flexbox to achieve it. This is a more of a question about css than it is about react.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                I am Div 1
            </div>
            <Child Component />
        </div>
    )
}


.container {
    display:flex;
}
```